# Замедление выполнения запросов после добавления FOREIGN KEY

Tags: sql, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy, foreign-key

Добрый день.

Есть база, которая периодически обновляется на основе некоторой выгрузки из внешнего источника. Всё взаимодействие с базой идёт через ORM sqlalchemy.
Обновление осуществляется следующим образом: для каждого элемента из выгрузки создаётся объект sqlalchemy, после чего для него выполняется DBSession.merge

База имеет поля id, parent_id, link_id и ещё несколько полей. Причём parent_id и link_id содержат id других строк в этой же таблице или NULL. Почти все строки имеют parent_id, но очень мало строк имеющих link_id.

Ранее существовал FOREIGN KEY и индекс для поля parent_id. Сегодня я добавил FOREIGN KEY для link_id. После этого я запустил скрипт обновления на основе выгрузки. Скорость выполнения упала многократно! Раньше скрипт спокойно отрабатывал за 2-3 часа, а сейчас за три часа он прошёл примерно треть элементов.

Дествительно ли виновато добавление FOREIGN KEY?

Поможет ли создание индекса для поля link_id?

Comment: `скрипт спокойно отрабатывал за 2-3 часа` - разрешите поинтересоваться примерными объёмами изменений (в примерном количестве обновляемых строк)

Comment: Индекс не поможет, потому что он уже есть. Ограничения внешнего ключа без индекса не работают.

Comment: @vp_arth, в выгрузке приходит 1330 элементов, относящихся именно к этой таблице. Но там ещё связи с другими таблицами, в двух из которых по несколько десятков тысяч строк, и я пока слабо представляю, как они завязаны, поскольку только недавно в этом проекте, и sql до этого знал только на уровне написания селектов :((

Comment: Без структур и примера импортируемых данных помочь сложно. Основная причина таких тормозов изначально - количество запросов в базу. Весь процесс импорта желательно собрать в пачки(гуглить bulk update)